# How can I make the key for a plot in Gnuplot not have transparency when the plot itself has transparency?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to make a "density" type scatter plot, where each point is a transparent circle, so when they overlap it makes a density map. I'm doing this with a huge number of samples, so the transparency is very low, but this means it's impossible to see the key. Can I make the key's transparency different than the actual plots?

This is what I have:

```
if (!exists("outfile")) outfile='plot.pdf'

set terminal pdf enhanced size 8in, 4.8in
set output outfile

set style fill transparent solid 0.1 noborder
set style circle radius 0.03

plot sample1 u 1:2 w circles, sample2 u 1:2 w circles
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Check `help keyentry`.

Comment: Just a thought: if you have 10'000 or many more data points, PDF (vector format) is maybe not the best format because it probably will become pretty large. PNG (bitmap format) might be better in this case.

Comment: @theozh I have 200,000 data points - the PDF is around 3.6 MB, but it does take a long time to render. I'm including this in a LaTeX report, so I just defaulted to PDF, but I'll switch to PNG if I'm not satisfied with the render time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `keyentry` and `with points pt 7`. Check `help keyentry`.

**Code:**

```
### keyentry
reset session

# create some random test data
set samples 10000
set table $Data1
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))+1):(invnorm(rand(0))+1) w table
set table $Data2
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))+4):(invnorm(rand(0))+4) w table
unset table

set style fill transparent solid 0.1 noborder
set style circle radius 0.03

plot $Data1 u 1:2 w circles notitle,\
     $Data2 u 1:2 w circles notitle, \
     keyentry w p pt 7 lc 1 title "Data1", \
     keyentry w p pt 7 lc 2 title "Data2"
### end of code
```

For older "pre-keyentry" gnuplot versions you could exchange the `keyentry` lines by:

```
 NaN w p pt 7 lc 1 title "Data1", \
 NaN w p pt 7 lc 2 title "Data2"
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I've read the documentation and this seems like what I need, but my version of gnuplot doesn't seem to recognize  `keyentry`. Ubuntu's repo has gnuplot up to Version 5.2.2 and the documentation says `keyentry` was added in 5.2. I'm trying to see if I can upgrade gnuplot right now.